# How to run C code after automatic C code generation with Matlab?

Tags: c, matlab, code-generation, codegen

I wrote a script in MATLAB and I am trying to generate C code.

I have not used C over the years so I am a little bit confused rn. I am using the MATLAB coder to generate C code automatically. This worked perfectly and now I am trying to open the C code in the Visual Studios environment and execute it. MATLAB coder did generate a C file called main.c. I guess it is an example of how to use the generated function appropriately. However, I am not able to run this program because I could not find the run button. Does anyone know, where the button is hidden?

Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuS2v.png)

Comment: What is that "Anfuegen" button with the green VCR "play" symbol?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-2-build?view=msvc-160) sounds like what you need.